# Один скрипт для разных систем

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

Мне необходимо записать последовательность действий в скрипт. Действиями будут (или могут быть) клонирование репозитория из Bitbucket, выполнение скрипта из клонированного репозитория, копирование файлов из клонированного репозитория в удаленную систему (IBM i), запуск команд в удаленной системе.

Сейчас подобное на Windows я сделал с помощью bat файла. Но мне необходимо, чтобы такой скрипт можно было запустить и из Windows и из Linux. На чем писать такой скрипт?

P.S. В Linux опыта работы нет. И в Windows и в Linux настроен доступ в Bitbucket и в IBM i по SSH (по ключу).

Comment: [bash](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-bash), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1479669/9435985), можно и на пыхе и любом другом ЯП, которым можно запускать внешние программы. Я бы выбрал bash

Comment: Спасибо! Выбрал bash.

Comment: @d7d1cd, учитывайте что bash скрипт на windows не запустится (без предварительной подготовки, типа установки Linux Subsystem for Windows или Mingw или Cygwin).

Comment: Спасибо. На Windows есть Git Bash.